# Rodar código Node ao apertar um botão no html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Bom dia senhores, sou iniciante em Node e em Javascript em geral, estou utilizando o express.js e quero que ao apertar o botao "ENVIAR" ele rode um codigo (que serve pra enviar um email):

[image: Print do meu HTML]

O codigo Node que quero rodar ao apertar o botao:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

function emailSend() {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "meuemail.Kappa@gmail.com",
      pass: "senha321" //nao 'e meu email kkkkkk

    }
  })

  transporter.sendMail({
    from: "Herbert Richard <meuemail.Kappa@gmail.com>",
    to: "kappa.canal@gmail.com",
    subject: "Teste de envio de email",
    text: "Ola, sou hebert richard e estou testando o nodemailer"
  }).then(message => {
    console.log(message);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Meu express:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html')
})

app.get("/style.css", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/src/style.css")
})

app.get("/runeterra-logo.png", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/runeterra-logo.png')
})

app.get("/wallpaper.jpg", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/wallpaper.jpg')
})

var server = app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo, primeiramente você está misturando um pouco as coisas, node é para o backend, oque você quer é que ao clicar um determinado botão ele mande a requisição para o backend poder enviar o email.

Em seu botão você irá colocar uma funçao para chamar essa requisição no frontend, aconselho você a usar axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) pois bem:

```
axios.get('/sendemail')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Certo que esse código acima deve ser aplicado ao metodo onClick no botão